# Kubernetes: Need advice deleting a list of pods with pause in-between deletions

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Good day.

Is there a Kubernetes pod deletion method for deleting a list of 48 pods while waiting until the previous pod has 'Running' status before deleting the next pod in the list?

I tried using a for loop with sleep in-between deletions, however, some pods take longer than others to re-spawn, sometimes up to 8 minutes.

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]. How are the pods named? What did your `for` loop look like?

Comment: What language are you implementing this in?  What manages the Pods; will `kubectl rollout restart deployment ...` do what you need?

Comment: @larsks - I was going to use a simple loop like this: `for pod in $(cat podList.txt) ; do kubectl -n $NS ${pod} ; sleep 180;done` However, some of the pods take anywhere from 2 minutes to 8 minutes to recreate, so I was thinking of doing a periodic (every 5 seconds) `kubectl get pods` to ensure ContainerCreating has finished before launching the next pod delete command.

Comment: Are these pods managed by a Deployment? If so, did you see @DavidMaze's comment? If not, how are they managed?

Comment: @David Maze, @larsks Yes, the pods are managed by a deployment server.  Also, this cluster runs replicasets in master/slave, so I'm not sure whether `kubectl rollout restart deployment` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Pods are being managed by a Deployment, `kubectl rollout restart deployment ...` will behave almost the way you describe.  Internally this changes an annotation on the Pod spec, and most other changes to a Deployment will behave similarly.  You don't need to manage this yourself.

In particular, with a [Rolling Update Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-update-deployment), Kubernetes will terminate and recreate Pods.  While there are a couple of more detailed controls described in the documentation, the standard behavior is that Kubernetes will immediately terminate 25% of the Pods, and immediately create new Pods up to a total of old and new Pods 25% above the `replicas:` value.  As these new Pods start to come on line and pass their health checks, more old Pods will be terminated  and replaced.  The important thing for your use case is that Kubernetes itself waits for the health checks to pass; you do not need to manually manage this yourself.

In your example with 48 replicas, Kubernetes will ensure that there are at least 36 replicas running (using the `maxUnavailable:` value) and there are at most 60 old and new replicas (using `maxSurge:`).  Say 12 old replicas get deleted, and 24 new ones are created.  As soon as the first new replica changes to `Running` status, Kubernetes will delete another old replica, so that there are always at least 36 running.  Kubernetes will manage this for you even if it takes several minutes for a new Pod to come up (assuming its health checks allow this).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information.   One other concern for me is that some of the pods have different replica counts. I will further discuss this solution with my colleague.

Comment: `kubectl rollout restart deployment ...` will honor the Deployment's replica count (the current replica count, if a HorizontalPodAutoscaler is changing it dynamically).  The example in the last paragraph assumes the `replicas: 48` from the question, and Kubernetes's default of `25%` for both parameters; all of these things can be changed in the Deployment spec.